# Why munin-node is not sending data to Mongo Monitoring Service (MMS)

Tags: munin, mongodb-mms

I've a munin-node running on Ubuntu 14.04. It's working fine. In terminal I can fetch data. I can telnet it using `telnet towhid 4949` But in hardware tab of MMS its showing `No data available`. What I'm missing here?

Comment: Is it accessible from the node the mms-agent runs on?

Comment: munin-node and mms-agent are running on the same machine. How will I check that mms-agent can access the munin-node?

Comment: Connect to the machine MMS is installed on and do a telnet to the hostname or IP it tries to reach munin-node. Furthermore, when you are connected to munin-node, try to do a fetch on "cpu", "iostat" and "iostat_iops" [as described in the docs](http://mms.mongodb.com/help/tutorial/configure-monitoring-munin-node/)

Comment: My hostname is `towhid` so I tried `telnet towhid 4949` and it looks fine. I've tried `fetch cpu` and get following result:
 
`user.value 113652
nice.value 5443
system.value 31957
idle.value 1357607
iowait.value 15831
irq.value 1
softirq.value 309
steal.value 0
guest.value 0`

Comment: Usually it is a DNS problem. You might want to have a look at munin-node's configuration file and check the `allow` parameters.